# Notepad2 alternative for Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone recommend a programmers editor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6536/can-anyone-recommend-a-programmers-editor)

I have recently started using a Mac. I am used to Notepad2 for handy text editing. I am used to its keyboard shortcuts and options and would like to have something similar on Mac.

I need something with shortcuts for:

- line deletion
- line duplication
- sorting lines alphabetical
- converting characters to unicode codes
- word wrapping

I also need at least:

- code highlighting
- tag autocompletion
- regex

What do you recommend?

Comment: There are a lot of questions on Ask Different already asking about text editors for the Mac. I'd recommend you use the search feature on this site to see if any of them are helpful.

Comment: I am sorry you feel this way. While list of programming editors are available both on and off this site, an user's response confirming features I require *exist* in some of them is very useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try MacVim. ViM is keybased by nature, so all functions have their shortcuts. If you haven't find some function binded, you can bind it yourself.

Also you can try Automator, Typinator and many other programs which works with any program you have

Comment: This is the only answer that at least tries to fit my question, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

TextMate and BBEdit are the most popular text editors of note on the Mac. You will find an equal number of people passionate about both pieces of software, so you will have to decide for yourself.

Both are extensible in a big way and have many different plug-ins or bundles available for download on the web.