# What's your favorite multi - editor on OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, text-editor

I was wondering if you could post your favorite code editor on OS X.

I'm looking for something lightweight (no netbeans or eclipse) for fast editing multi languages. tag highlighting and code completion highly appreciated :).

On Windows I was using Notepad++ a lot and was really satisfied with it.

btw - I don't like dashcode so much - that's why I am looking for an alternative :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone recommend a programmers editor?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6536/can-anyone-recommend-a-programmers-editor)

Comment: There are [a lot of questions that have already been answered on this site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=text+editor) asking about recommending a text editor. You might want to look at those responses; there are some good ones.

Comment: possibly right :) thanks for the hint though - haven't found this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BBEdit's latest release is REALLY good. I first encountered BB way back in the day on OS7, and it was more editor than I needed at the time, and it only confused me. Since then I've become a much heavier-duty text editor user, and when they brought out a new release a couple months ago I pulled the trigger.

It's EXCELLENT. Every feature I've wanted, it's had for me, waiting to discover. Can't recommend it highly enough. You can find it on the App Store.

Comment: thanks for this. BBedit looks really great. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/). I, too, use Notepad++ on Windows.

Comment: just downloaded this one and will give it a try too since it is freeware ;)

Answer (score 2):

BBEdit is excellent, I program more for the iPhone or Mac these days which means I'm always using Xcode, but when I am doing anything web oriented, BBEdit is my first choice.

Answer (score 2):

[Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/), or the version that comes with OS X.  I use this for all of my documenting, coding, and paper writing (with LaTeX, and usually [Org-Mode](http://orgmode.org/)).

Answer (score 2):

Of course VIM, you can use [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) or use vim in terminal or use vim in [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home)

Comment: Is CodeRunner any good?

Comment: Sorry never used coderunner.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite is Sublime Text 2.

http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-beta

It supports TM bundles and it works on windows/mac/linux.

Answer (score 1):

Eclips, Aptana, CodeEdit, TeXtMate, XCode Coda,... There are indeed plenty of solutions, depending on what you want to do. PHP, Java, .NET,... Each language has it's own preferred editor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that **gedit** is also available for Mac OS X.:
http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/